# using + sign in .split is giving error why

Tags: java

```
String a = jTextField1.getText();
String b = a.replace('x','1');

String c = b;

String array [] = c.split("+");
String one = array[0];
String two = array[1];
String three = array[2];
jLabel3.setText(array[0]);
```

Comment: What is the error. can you attach stack trace?

Comment: What is the "error" (i.e. full stack trace if runtime error, or full build error output if build-time error), including which line in your code it is referring to (if any)?

Comment: using + sign .split("+") is giving error

Comment: Add the error into the question, but it looks like the String array is being declared wrong...move the [] so it becomes "String[] array = c.split("+");"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is beacause `split` accepts regular expressions, and `+` is a special characeter, escape it and you will be fine.

```
String array [] = c.split("\\+");
```

Comment: Thanks Friends for your active support

Answer (score 2):

The [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method uses a regular expression. You need to escape the expression using `\\`.

```
String array [] = c.split("\\+");
```

Or you can use the Pattern class to escape a regex

```
String array [] = c.split(Pattern.quote("+"));
```